# Image inside a div doesn’t work using DOCTYPE declaration

Tags: css, html, background

I am trying to show images inside two divs.

It works fine if I don’t use the DOCTYPE declaration (http://csspruebas.comule.com/without_doctype.html ) but if I use DOCTYPE declaration doesn’t work (http://csspruebas.comule.com/with_doctype.html), only it is showed the image of the second div. For other purposes I need the DOCTYPE declaration so how can I show both images using DOCTYPE declaration? Thank you very much for your help!!!

This is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 4.01 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>HTML WITH DOCTYPE</title>
<style>
    p { margin-bottom: 1em; padding-left:30px; padding-right:30px; }
</style>
</head>

<body marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" align="justify">

<div style="background-image:url('bg1.gif');width:13%;height:100%;float:left;"> 
</div>
<div style="background-    image:url('bg2.jpg');width:87%;height:100%;float:right;overflow:auto">

    <p>AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA</p>
    <p>AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA</p>
    <p>AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA</p>
    <p>AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA</p>
    <p>AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA</p>
    <p>AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA</p>
    <p>AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA</p>
    <p>AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA</p>
    <p>AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA</p>
    <p>AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA</p>
    <p>AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA</p>
    <p>AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA</p>
    <p>AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA</p>
    <p>AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA</p>
    <p>AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA</p>
    <p>AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA</p>
    <p>AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA</p>
    <p>AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA</p>
    <p>AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA</p>
    <p>AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA</p>
    <p>AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA</p>
    <p>AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add CSS rule

```
html, body {
  height:100%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much kei!! Now it works fine!! But now with this divs structure page I see that there is another problem: when I add a shockwave button to the page, if I see the page in Android 4.0.3 mobile browser the button moves from its position when I go up or down the page (in other browsers like Chrome, Firefox... the button doesn’t move, it only moves from its position in Android mobile browser). You can see this behaviour in: http://csspruebas.comule.com/with_doctype.html. How can I avoid this behaviour in Android mobile browser? Thank you very much!!

Comment: That's a whole different issue. Create another question for it.

Comment: Ok! Thank you!! I have created another post with this question ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21167557/button-moving-over-the-div-in-android-browser-how-can-i-maintain-the-button-fix ).